# How to use a getter function inside a React component?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, hardhat

I am trying to make a basic React component to retrieve a value from a deployed contract. In this example, I am using an input box to receive a contract address (which is a deployed address of  an ERC20 token on localhost) and populates the `addr` state variable of the `Balance` component.

When the `Get Balance` Button is clicked, the contract's max_supply should be retrieved and the `balance` state variable should be updated with that value.

I am able to deploy the ERC20 token contract.  However, I am unable to retrieve the value of the `s_maxSupply()` getter from within my `Balance` component. Is this even possible? If not, any alternatives would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import OilToken from '../artifacts/contracts/OilToken.sol/OilToken.json'


const Balance = () => {
    const [addr, setAddr] = useState('---');
    const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);
    let _balance = 0;

    async function getBalanceFromContract() {

        if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
            const [account] = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(addr, OilToken.abi, provider)
            _balance = contract.s_maxSupply();
        }
    }

    function _setBalance() {
        getBalanceFromContract();
        setBalance(_balance);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <br />
            <input onChange={e => setAddr(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter account address" value={addr} />
            <button onClick={_setBalance}>Get Balance</button>
            <br />
            <div>The Max Supply of tokens is: {balance}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Balance
```

The ERC20 token is provided below for completeness.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Votes.sol";

contract OilToken is ERC20Votes {
    uint256 public s_maxSupply = 1000 * 10**18;

    mapping 

    constructor() ERC20("OilToken", "OIL") ERC20Permit("GovernanceToken") {
        _mint(msg.sender, s_maxSupply);
    }


 
    function _afterTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override(ERC20Votes) {
        super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint256 amount) internal override(ERC20Votes) {
        super._mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you wrap the code in `try/catch` inside if statement and then see what kind of error you are getting.

Comment: [[PromiseResult]]: Error: network does not support ENS (operation="getResolver", network="unknown", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.6.5) at Logger.makeError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7872:19) at...

Comment: Probably you are passing wrong arguments to the contract

Comment: ``_balance = await contract.s_maxSupply();`` add the await keyword here. Also according to your error params that you are passing are wrong. What address are you suing to call the contract in ``ethers.Contract(addr, OilToken.abi, provider)``

Comment: Yes, I did pass the wrong argument at first. I resolved it and still was unable to console.log (_balance). The error had something to do with BigNumbres so (in the solidity contract) I changed  s_maxSupply data type to UINT8 and it works! this only opens another rabbit hole to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

contract.s_maxSupply() will return promise so you need to write it like this

```
_balance = await contract.s_maxSupply();
```